# Bootstrap Confirmation Dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a page that asks the user if they want to actually do something. Currently, it works like this:

```
<a href="/do/this/thing/1234" onclick="return promptUser();">Do This Thing</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function promptUser() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to do this thing?");
  }
</script>
```

Now, the user wants to add some graphics, etc to the dialog. For that reason, I want to use the Bootstrap Modal window as I have it elsewhere in my code. I've added the following:

```
<div id="confirmDialog" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to do this thing?
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirmed">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">No</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I'm not sure how to wire up the interaction with the link. If the user says "No", I want to stay on the page. If the user says "Yes", I want to redirect the user to the url in the `href`. How do I set this up?

Thanks

Comment: Which bootstrap version you are using ?

Comment: @KaushikThanki Version 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    click me
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm">confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#confirm').on('click', funciton(){
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#confirmed').click(function(){
location.href = "some URL "
});
```

It will stay on no as it's default behavior or bootstrap modal and we have attached event on yes button on mention above.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but things have moved on in the last few years. For reference, in case anyone else needs to ask the same question, it might be easier to wrap the modal in a form, and use an input to respond:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <form action="letsdothisthing.php method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary value="YES" ></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```